# Button with NavigationLink and function call SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-button

I have an issue with NavigationLinks with conditions. It doesn't react what I'm expected. When a user click on the button the function "test" must be called and give a return value. If the return value is true the "SheetView" must be openend directly without clicking on the NavigationLink text. Please could someone give me a help on this one. Thanks in advance

I made a small (sample) program for showing the issue.

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoginView: View {
   @State var check = false
   @State var answer = false
   
    var body: some View {
       NavigationView {
         VStack{
            Text("it doesn't work")
            Button(action: {
                answer = test(value: 2)
                if answer {
                    //if the return value is true then directly navigate to the sheetview
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: SheetView(),
                        label: {
                            Text("Navigate")
                        })
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Calculate")
            })
            
        
         }
       }
    }
    
    func test(value: Int) -> Bool {
     
            if value == 1 {
                check = false
            } else {
                print("Succes")
                check = true
            }
        
        return check
    }
       
}


struct SheetView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                Text("Test")
                    .font(.title)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer from Yodagama works if you were trying to present a sheet (because you called your navigation destination SheetView), but if you were trying to navigate to SheetView instead of present a sheet, the following code would do that.

```
struct LoginView: View {
   @State var check = false
   @State var answer = false
   
    var body: some View {
       NavigationView {
         VStack{
            Text("it doesn't work")
            NavigationLink(destination: SheetView(), isActive: $answer, label: {
                Button(action: {
                    answer = test(value: 2)
                }, label: {
                    Text("Calculate")
                })
            })
            
            
        
         }
       }
    }
    
    func test(value: Int) -> Bool {
     
            if value == 1 {
                check = false
            } else {
                print("Succes")
                check = true
            }
        
        return check
    }
       
}


struct SheetView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                Text("Test")
                    .font(.title)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks for your answer. It's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
struct LoginView: View {
   @State var check = false
   @State var answer = false
   
    var body: some View {
       NavigationView {
         VStack{
            Text("it doesn't work")
            Button(action: {
                answer = test(value: 2)
                //<= here
            }, label: {
                Text("Calculate")
            })
            
        
         }
         .sheet(isPresented: $answer, content: {  //<= here
            SheetView()
         })
       }
    }
    
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, actually I'm not looking for a sheet (maybe I chose the wrong name for that struct), but just for a normal view where I can navigate. Any idea how I could do that?

Comment: Yes I've got my answer. Thanks all for your help! Really appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
@State private var route: Bool = false

// use the modifier for the button    

.navigationDestination(isPresented: $route, destination: {
            DestinationView()
        }

// and wrap the parent view in NavigationStack
```

Comment: Work only for ios 16 or newer